# SignalR can't connect to hub when using Azure Service Bus backplane

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, azureservicebus

I downloaded the [SignalR Getting Started solution](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SignalR-Getting-Started-b9d18aa9) and it works well. However if I [add Azure Service Bus backplane](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus) then the client can't connect any more.

First it tries to connect to WebSocket

> SCRIPT12030: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030, The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

Then falls back to long polling and it doesn't work either.

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.

Running it locally, debugging and there is no exception thrown on the server side.

The only difference between the working and non-working status is in the Startup.cs if I comment out the `UseServiceBus` part then it works:

```
//GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(connectionString, "Blabla"); 
app.MapSignalR();
```

Obviously I can't leave it like this for Azure deployment.

I tried upgrading / downgrading packages, both `SignalR` and `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`, all the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running behind a firewall by any chance? Could be that ASB is getting blocked.

Comment: No firewall. Looks like it has something to do with the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus library. I managed to make it work by removing the official library and replacing it with a fixed version made by Mark Heath: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3548#issuecomment-231030083

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error, i have seen that the response for https://localhost/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets.... is 400 the problem is that my service bus Pricing plan is basic but only Standard tire to support Topics. So you have to go to azure portal and under the "Pricing tire" section of service bus you have to specifically go to the settings and scaled it up from Basic to Standard.

Comment: I was using standard. It turns out to be fixed by an unofficial library, see my comment above.